# How do you disable account activation in WPMU and then log the user in right away?

Tags: multisite, users, activation

Is there a way to disable account activation for WPMU then log the user in and redirect them to another page?

I am running on WPMU with BuddyPress.

Answer (score 1):

In a WPMU setup the account information is sent to the wp_signup table before being passed to the wp_users table.

an easy fix for this is:

```
function your_disable_activation( $user, $user_email, $key, $meta = '' ) {
    // Activate the user
    $user_id = wpmu_activate_signup( $key );

    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, true, is_ssl() );

    wp_redirect( /*redirect to */ site_url() );
    exit;

}
add_filter( 'wpmu_signup_user_notification', 'your_disable_activation', 10, 4 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for future reference:

Currently: **WordPress 4.5** (Date: 04/28/16 | With the nag message to update to WP 4.5.1)

My tweaked version:

```
// -- Originally in the post, not sure if this is necessary
// -- remove_filter('wpmu_signup_blog_notification', 'activate_on_blog_signup');

// This function runs after Sign Up Step 2
function activate_user_and_blog( $domain, $path, $title, $user, $user_email, $key, $meta ) {
  // Activate website right blog registration
  $blogID = wpmu_activate_signup($key);

  // Get the URL of the new blog
  $blogURL = get_blogaddress_by_id($blogID['blog_id']);

  // Redirect the user to their blog Dashboard
  wp_redirect(trailingslashit($blogURL) . 'dashboard');

  // wp_redirect( home_url() );  // Redirect to home page
  exit;
}
add_filter('wpmu_signup_blog_notification', 'activate_user_and_blog', 10, 7 );
```

Originally found via: https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/skip-redirect-past-the-congratulations-your-blog-is-ready